# ASP.NET MVC - Make ExceptionContext return normal response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We are working on new MVC5 web apps in which we are using existing API libraries for certain functionalities.

Now, these API libraries throws certain exception types which needs to be communicated back to the client browser.

How I want the handling of these exceptions to work is:

1. If the called action returns a view, then take the user to a page with the exception message
2. If the called action returns a JSON string, then return the response in string format

My concern now is with #2 since the controller's 'OnException' method always returns a server error and by default ASP.NET will return a default custom error unless otherwise I change the web app configuration as follows

```
<system.web> 
...
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
<system.webServer>
...
   <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

My question is, how do I return the JSON string from the 'OnException' without having to change the web configuration as shown above?  (i.e. promote the ExceptionContext to return a regular JSON response string).

TIA

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //If the exeption is already handled we do nothing
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Init
        var vm = new ExceptionViewModel();
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
        var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        // Get action return type
        Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
        var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);
        Type returnType = null;

        // If method is null, default to JSONREsult
        if (method == null)
        {
            returnType = typeof(JsonResult);
        }
        else
        {
            returnType = method.ReturnType;
        }

        // Log exception
        vm.ErrorLogId = LogException(ex);

        // Assign Exception View Model
        if (ex is MyCustomExceptionType)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            vm.ErrorMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        }
        else if (ex is NotAuthorizedException)
        {
            // Get Http exception
            var httpEx = ex as NotAuthorizedException;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = httpEx.GetHttpCode();
            vm.ErrorMessage = httpEx.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set status code to 500 since this exception block indicates an application
            // exception occurred
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            vm.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, I may have malfunctioned. Toink!";
        }

        // Prepare data to return back to client
        if (returnType.Equals(typeof(JsonResult)) || returnType.Equals(typeof(Task<JsonResult>)))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = vm.ErrorMessage,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "Error",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(vm)
            };
        }

        // Mark exception as a handled
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```